# nginx rewrite url changes url in browser too

Tags: nginx

here is my nginx config for port 80.

```
location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location /admin {
        rewrite ^ https://$host:7000$request_uri permanent;
    }
```

what I want is when user types http://mywebsite.com/admin , url has to become https://mywebsite.com:7000. the thing is url doesn't change internally and it also gets changed in browser. How do I do that so browser url doesn't get changed?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a [Reverse Proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#pass).

Try this:

```
location / {
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location /admin {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:7000;
    }
```

If your service running on non-ssl port, then use `http://localhost:7000;` instead.

Comment: Thanks,but when I used this, it doesn't load the js/css files at all and says 404 not found .

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili:  think you have to add a `/` after the port: `proxy_pass https://localhost:7000/`.

Comment: I added it. still not working.

Comment: @NikaKhurashvili: then check your nginx logfiles at */var/log/nginx* or wherever you have configured your logs to go to.

Comment: Do you only want to load only specific file types from `/admin` and not css/js files?

Comment: jpg, png ,css,js and some more.

Comment: From where? Port 80 or from port 7000? Please give examples for the URLs that are not working with full path. Or do you want to map `/admin` to `https://localhost:7000/admin` instead?

Comment: I want to map /admin to https://localhost:7000 . when I go to https://localhost/admin  i want it to load https://localhost:7000 , but css and js files say 404 not found

Comment: I want to load css/js from port 7000 when accessing http://localhost/admin, but if I access http://localhost , it's default(no proxy)

Comment: So basically what happens is, nginx tries to search css and js files from port 7000 in the current directory, not from port 7000's locations.

Comment: do you understand?

Comment: I think the problem is that your admin application is not mapped on path `/admin` (on port 7000). If it was, then all resources would be mapped 1:1 from port 80 to 7000. If your css is normally requested from `https://localhost:7000/css/admin.css`, then the request fails with the reverse proxy, because on port 80 the resource doesn't exist, but it is available on `http://mywebsite.com/admin/css/admin.css`.

Comment: Is port 7000 served from an Apache or Tomcat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93263/discussion-between-nika-khurashvili-and-freddy).